# Symfony with XAMPP on Windows XP SP3/Again/

Tags: php, symfony1, xampp

This is what I get when try to run "generate:app frontend" :

```
C:\>php xampp\htdocs\development\sfprojects\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\s
ymfony generate:app frontend
PHP Warning:  require_once(C:\config/..xampp/htdocs/development/sfprojects/jobee
t/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php): failed to open stre
am: No such file or directory in C:\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on lin
e 3

Warning: require_once(C:\config/..xampp/htdocs/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib
/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php): failed to open stream: N
o such file or directory in C:\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\config/..xampp/htd
ocs/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload
.class.php' (include_path='.;C:C:\xampp\php\pear') in C:\config\ProjectConfigura
tion.class.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\config/..xampp/htdocs/d
evelopment/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.clas
s.php' (include_path='.;C:C:\xampp\php\pear') in C:\config\ProjectConfiguration.
class.php on line 3

C:\>
```

I thought it's something with PEAR, but I cant find a way to figure it out, nor I'm 100% it's PEAR, so...glad to get some help on the issue.
  What I've already tried is to rewrite multiple times php.ini if there's problem with locating pear.php, but I think, I tried all scenarios possible and that's not the solutions.So what to do from now on.
 Thanks
-Leron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd` into `xampp\htdocs\development\sfprojects\jobeet` and run the command.

Also you may have the require path wrong if you created this as an embeded install (ie. you embeded symfony in `lib/vendor` of the project) Youre missing a slash:

`C:\config/..xampp/htdocs/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php`

should be:

`C:\config/../xampp/htdocs/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php`

So you need to change your require_once statement in `projectConfiguration.class.php`.

But that could just be because youre invoking the command from outside the project (although technically that should work if you have everything set up correct)...

Comment: That's what I get when I changed the path - "Could not open input file : xampp\htdocs\development\sfprojects\jobeet".Just from curiosity I put the symfony.bat file in the jobeet dierctory but think this is not the problem.I follow the official guide and I think the command line is right and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I think that still it could be PEAR that's making the problem.This doubt comes from the fact that when I tried to run go-pear.bat file I receive this: manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB in phar "C:\xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar"PH
P Warning:  require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php): failed to open stream:
phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in
C:\xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar on line 1236

Warning: require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php): failed to open stream: pha
r error: invalid url or non-existent phar "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in C:\

Comment: xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar on line 1236
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: As far as PEAR, that should be installed with XAMPP **[see this question on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/255940/problem-with-installing-pear-xampp)**... but PEAR should not be at issue here as long as `symfony generate:project` succeeded because if you are following the jobeet tutorial youll be converting the generated project from using the pear installation to using an embedded installation - so you need to download or set up an svn external to symfony in `lib/vendor/symfony`. If you havent done this or if you project failed to generate these are your problems, not PEAR.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it - "generate:project jobeet" was successful, I got the directory structure that was described in the tutorial, and the next step was to run "generate:app frontend" where I reach into these troubles.I don't see what svn could have in common here.

Comment: Problem solved.Thanks prodigitalson.It was the slash in the include path.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ahh.. well normally you would generate a complete project structure with that command... i thought jobeet did that, but may you make it manually... its been a long time since i went through it.

Comment: Also jsuding by your rep you are new here... So if my answer fixed you problem then click on the check next to it and mark the question as answered. If you feel that you answered your own question, then post that answer as such and mark it as the answer when you are able (for me i have to wait 48 hours, you might have to wait longer). I also knwo you have asked a few questions the past few days... you should go back and mark answers for those as well if you consider them answered. :-)